# Sending data back to the intent

Tags: java, android

I`m trying to send data from my second activity back to the the first one. After creating an instance in my second activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Name",Name);
startActivity(i);
```

I`m using onResume method in my first activity to process the sent data, however the onResume seems to never be called when I go back. How do I trigger it?

Comment: Use startactivityforresult in first activity and receive result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to start the second activity using the startActivityForResult. For example:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 2); // the 2 is the request code
```

And we also need to implement onActivityResult inside the FirstActivity:

```
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

    // Check if the request code corresponds to SecondActivity  
    // You can also check if resultCode has the value you were expecting
    if(requestCode==2) {
        // Retrieve the information passed. A message string in our case
        String message=data.getStringExtra("Message");
    }  
}
```

And finally, in SecondActivity, use this to finish and pass data back:

```
String message = "Going back to First Activity";  
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.putExtra("Message", message);  
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); // RESULT_OK is just an integer predefined by Android. You can pass your own value, if needed
finish();
```

You might also want to check out [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Answer (score 0):

you can use public static object which will hold the shared data between the two activities. as you can edit its properties in the second activity and no need to send it back to the first one

Answer (score 0):

You have to use startActivityForResult() from Activity A and then when you are done with processing the result from B, handle the result back in Activity A by overriding onActivityResult().